# Google Now Event ticketToken barcodes

Tags: android, gmail, schema.org, google-now

Does anybody have any idea how to get a barcode to show in the Google Now Event Reservation?

According to the [schema specification](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/reference/event-reservation) I just need to include the ticketToken parameter and value, either as a URL to an image of the barcode, or as the barcode string.

I wish to recreate an Aztec barcode from an encoded string of characters, but when using the [email markup tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/) I am told that "ticketToken" is an unknown property. This is the case even when simply copying and pasting Google's own demo code into the validator.

So, does anybody know whether it is the code at fault, or the validator?

Does anybody have any working examples of a barcode being generated by the Google Now system itself upon providing it with a valid string of characters?

Comment: Today, the validator is happy with `ticketToken`